# Profit, Loss and percentage problem.

Tags: arithmetic

A dishonest businessman professes to sell his articles at **cost price** but he uses false weight by which **he cheats by 10% while buying and 10% while selling**. find his **profit percentage**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item that should cost $1$ is bought for $0.9$ and sold for $1.1$.  Do you define profit percentage on the buying price or the selling price?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the original cost of the article is 100.

In the process of buying, he cheats by 10%. This means he only paid 90 for it.

He will sell it ***at his cost price*** (90), with a 10% cheating. This means he obtained a payment of 99.

Now, the (original) cost price is 90, and the (new) selling price is 99. Can you find the profit percent?